# Show popover with url and option to open in new window

Tags: theme-development, block-editor

I am creating a custom block and I want to show a button which the user can edit the text of and I want them to be able to select a page/enter a link. I have this working but using `URLInputButton` does not give the option to open in a new tab like the default wordpress popover when you highlight some text and then choose to add a hyperlink.

This is what I currently have:

```
<URLInputButton url={url} onChange={onURLChange} />
```

I have also played around with a popover but not sure how to put what I want in there. This just does what it says and shows text that says 'Popover is toggled!"

```
<Button variant="secondary" onClick={toggleVisible}>
     Toggle Popover!
     {isVisible && <Popover>Popover is toggled!</Popover>}
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no support for such a setting in `URLInputButton`/`URLInput` and those components are deprecated. Try [`LinkControl`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-editor/src/components/link-control/README.md). It may be helpful to study its [use in the core Button block](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/button/edit.js#L218-L248). That seems similar to what you are building.